# Using Json Web Tokens with Flask-Oauthlib

Tags: python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, json-web-token, flask-oauthlib

For a client project I am developing a web app that is using Flask for the backend.

So I decided to use Flask-oauthlib in a attempt to make supplying refresh tokens, and revoking access tokens simple. However, there is something I am still having a hard time wrapping my head around.

When writing the oauth server, how can I have it generate and serve JSON Web Tokens over using the default access/refresh tokens?

Another thing I would also like to know is how would I go about validating JSON Web Tokens from http requests?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find anything? How do we use JWT in flask-oauthlib?

Comment: Do you think I would have posted an answer if I already did? smh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of Flask-OAuthlib. It is hard to implement such thing with this library. I have created a new library which is [Authlib](https://authlib.org/). With this library, it would be quite easy to create an OAuth server as you described.

Authlib itself has JWT included. First, learn how to create JWT and validate JWT on https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/specs/rfc7519.html

For generating access token and refresh token, you can configure it with

`OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_GENERATOR` and `OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN_GENERATOR` as described on https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/oauth2.html#define-server